# Получить данные из PUT

Tags: php

В php для получения данных из POST и GET есть соответствующие методы, но как получить данные например из PUT ?

Пробовал `$HTTP_POST_VARS['name'];` не получается

Comment: вот тут можно [почитать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941207/http-protocols-put-and-delete-and-their-usage-in-php) - и про PUT и про DELETE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как рекомендует php.net. Получать данные из потока stdin

```
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

/* Открываем файл на запись */
$fp = fopen("myputfile.ext", "w");

/* Читаем 1 KB данных за один раз
   и пишем в файл */
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
  fwrite($fp, $data);

/* Закрываем потоки */
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
```